# React iframe sandbox don't allow anything

Tags: html, reactjs, iframe, sandbox

I have a requirement to use iframe sandbox in React application. In which, I don't want to allow anything and restrict everything.

So when I am passing sandbox as blank, something like:-

```
<iframe
  frameBorder="0"
  ref={(container) => { this.container[index] = container; }}
  srcDoc={thread.body}
  sandbox
/>
```

I am getting this - "Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `sandbox`."

react: "^16.5.2"

Answer (score 3):

React treats `<iframe sandbox />` just like it was `<iframe sandbox={true} />` which is not correct here.

Based on the docs here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp, browser expects sandbox prop to be an empty value.

You should simply use

```
<iframe
  frameBorder="0"
  ref={(container) => { this.container[index] = container; }}
  srcDoc={thread.body}
  sandbox=""
/>
```

**EDIT:**

As OP answered in the comments, he had to do `sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-popups"`.

Comment: thanx for the answer. I tried that also and facing some cross-origin issue because of that (as I am resizing my iframe on onLoad)

Comment: I guess that this is expected behavior. You won't be able to resize it if you restrict everything. Try `sandbox="allow-same-origin"`.

Comment: yes, its working with `sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-popups"`.

Added, `allow-popups` to make links workable inside iframe body.

Comment: I'm glad I helped. Mark the answer.